# Scala Actors and dropped entry

Tags: scala, actor

I have a scala actor implementation that basically does an average. I push an entry maintaing a total and a count and figure out the average. what's happening is when i run this in a tight loop during a test, i miss an entry, and I believe it's the last one.
the actor is like this:

```
val actor = new Actor { def act = react { 
  case v: Long => addEntry(v); act
  case _ => ()
}}.start()
```

Edit: the implementation of addEntry is this:

```
  private def addEntry(v: Long) {
    total = total + v
    count = count + 1
    avg   = total / count
  }
```

and the add is basically `actor ! 10` and so on

after i call stop in the test, i wait about 200ms to make sure the queue is processed. (or i think that's what i am doing, is this where the problem is?)

Edit2: Basically, i think right now that because I was setting these values in a tight loop and then calling exit immediately, the last entry or entries was/were not being processed or were being dropped. I put a small sleep between the end of the loop (actually it's a CountDownLatch.await and actor.stop and now i can't make the test fail.

Comment: Can you show the implementation of `addEntry(v)` and how you submit messages to actor?

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation enters only the `react` as long as you get a `Long` otherwise it stops. You could wrap it with `loop`, which is equivalent to `while (true)`, and add a matching expression to stop the `actor` instead. `actor ! 10` will not match `case v: Long => ...` because an `Int` is sent to the actor and so the actor will stop.

```
val actor = new Actor {
  def act() = { 
    loop { 
      react {
        case "stop" => exit()      // you might create a messageobject instead
        case l: Long => addEntry(l)
        case i: Int => addEntry(i.toLong)
      }
    }
  }
}.start()
```

This would be my suggestion.

Comment: if you notice, i call act recursively from the addEntry(long), which is essentially the same as using the loop outside of it. Also, in my implementation i only care about long's.

Comment: Yes, I noticed it, but it is not good practice. And yes, you only care about Longs, but you sent an Int to the Actor, so I wanted to cover that case as well.